# Clone select options failed to append it to new element

Tags: jquery, select, clone

I am trying to clone select options and append it to new select element created dynamically,

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var addRowNut = 2;


       $('#addNewNutritionButton').on('click', function (e) {
          // clone select options
           var labelOptions = $('#label1 > option').clone();
           console.log(labelOptions);
           $('#NutBoxesGroup').append('<div id="nutGroup' + addRowNut + '"> <label>Nutrition label </label>' +
               '<select id="label' + addRowNut + '"></select>' + '</div>');

                $('input[name=nutCount]').val(addRowNut);

         // append to created select 
               $('#label'+ addRowNut ).append(labelOptions);
                  addRowNut++;
                return false;

            });
           });
```

and here is a running example of my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/TaEzZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong selector `#label1` . `select` has name as `label1` not `ID` .

Use this - **[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**,

```
var labelOptions = $('select[name=label1] > option').clone();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaEzZ/4/)**

Also, `$('input[name=nutCount]').val(addRowNut);`

There is no reference to this `input` element in your markup.

Comment: @TilwinJoy i already +1 ned it, since OP has provided a hard to read code, well he managed to find out the main issue... :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line `var labelOptions = $('#label1 > option').clone();` where you are trying to select an id which doesn't exist. To solve the problem you need to add an ID to your HTML code `<select id="label1" name="label1">` or select with `var labelOptions = $('select[name="label1"] option').clone();`